# Thread hangs on calling getResultList()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a strange problem with JPA. In my sheduler executing next code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Transactional
 public void refreshSmsStatuses() {
    try {
        log.info("Enter refreshSmsStatuses");

        EntityManager em = hibernateHelper.getEntityManager();

        log.info("EM created");

        List<Sms> lSms = null;

        log.info("lSms = null;");

        TypedQuery<Sms> smsQuery = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT sms FROM Sms AS sms 
             join sms.status as status 
             WHERE status.isFinal = 0 
             and sms.remoteId is not null 
             and sms.sendDate > sysdate - 3", Sms.class);

        log.info("sqlQuery created");

        lSms = smsQuery.getResultList();

        log.info("Query SMS executed");
        .....
```

After planning nighty reboot it works several times and hangs. There are next strings

```
2018-12-17 00:10:33,802 [SmsDao.java:pool-2-thread-1:166] - lSms = null;
2018-12-17 00:10:33,802 [SmsDao.java:pool-2-thread-1:168] - sqlQuery created
```

in log files. The query does not execute in DB, it hangs somewhere in JPA. Problem is on only production server. After hanging any sheduler's methods don't work, because, I think they wait for the end of this method.
If anybody run into with similar problem, please help me.
Thanks a lot

UPDATED

```
@Table( name = "ZUSB_SMS") 
@Entity
public class Sms extends BaseModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3624326750555670797L;
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "generator", sequenceName = "ZUSB_SMS_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REF_SMS_TEMPLATE_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SmsTemplate template;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "send_date")
    private Date sendDate;
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REF_CLIENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Client client;
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REF_SMS_STATUS_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SmsStatus status;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REF_USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;
    @Column(name = "remote_id")
    private Long remoteId;
    private String log = "";

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REF_CLE_STATUS_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SmsCleStatus cleStatus;
    @Column(name = "cle_text")
    private String cleText;
    @Column(name = "cle_id")
    private Long cleId;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public SmsTemplate getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }
    public void setTemplate(SmsTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }
    public Date getSendDate() {
        return sendDate;
    }
    public void setSendDate(Date sendDate) {
        this.sendDate = sendDate;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }
    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public SmsStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(SmsStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Long getRemoteId() {
        return remoteId;
    }
    public void setRemoteId(Long remoteId) {
        this.remoteId = remoteId;
    }
    public String getLog() {
        return log;
    }

    public void setLog(String log) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();        
        String reportDate = df.format(today);
        if(log.equals(""))
            this.log = reportDate + " " + log;
        else
            this.log = this.log + "\n" + reportDate + " " + log;
    }

    public SmsCleStatus getCleStatus() {
        return cleStatus;
    }

    public void setCleStatus(SmsCleStatus cleStatus) {
        this.cleStatus = cleStatus;
    }

    public String getCleText() {
        return cleText;
    }

    public void setCleText(String cleText) {
        this.cleText = cleText;
    }

    public Long getCleId() {
        return cleId;
    }

    public void setCleId(Long cleId) {
        this.cleId = cleId;
    }






}
```

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: what was the error message?

Comment: Are you sure your query is not running forever, that is a strange looking join? And why is everything named `sms`, table, column, alias, (domain?) it makes the query  so hard to read

Comment: There is not any error messages. On that line tread just hangs

Comment: you are joining `ON` what? and why do you even need a `join` ? May be you want a query like this - `FROM Sms s 
             WHERE s.isFinal = 0 
             and s.remoteId is not null 
             and s.sendDate > sysdate - 3`
can you show us your `SMS` class?

Comment: Joakim Danielson. Maybe it is a little bit ugly, I have changed the query "SELECT smsAlias FROM Sms AS smsAlias join smsAlias.status as statusAlias WHERE statusAlias.isFinal = 0 and smsAlias.remoteId is not null and smsAlias.sendDate>sysdate-3"

Erfan Ahmed Emon.

Comment: try this query instead - `FROM Sms s WHERE s.status.isFinal = 0 and s.remoteId is not null and s.sendDate > sysdate - 3`

Comment: Why the `hibernateHelper.getEntityManager()` that doesn't feel right, you should simply use `@PersistenceContext` on a field of type `EntityManager` and use that.  Looks like you are obtaining things outside the scope of Spring. Do things in the way they should be done and delete your `HibernateHelper`.

Comment: My EntityManager is declared in HibernateHelper like 

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

Comment: If you think something is hung then get the thread dump and show people what is hung, and at what call.

Answer (score -1):

First, your query is not correct since you didn't specify `ON` what you are joining. Second, You don't need to `join` `SmsStatus` table explicitly since you mapped it with `@ManyToOne`.

Update your *query* like this-

```
TypedQuery<Sms> smsQuery = em.createQuery(
        "FROM Sms s                            
         WHERE s.status.isFinal = 0
         AND s.remoteId IS NOT NULL   
         AND s.sendDate > sysdate-3", Sms.class);
```

This may solve the problem.

Comment: Just putting a basic JOIN in a query is NOTHING to do with a thread hang; it is a totally normal thing to do when you want to define the join explicitly. To debug a thread hang you do a thread dump and see what is actually HUNG, or just look at the JPA provider log

Comment: Billy Frost, your version looks rightly. Today I will try to swich on log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa=DEBUG. But,unfortunally this problem can disapper for some time. I hope logging will help me

Comment: First time looking into the code it was clear that OP's query wasn't correct. Therefore trivial assumption was to correct the query. I agree my answer didn't fully meet op's question but it wasn't entirely wrong!